# rotating an object without changing its orientation

Tags: rotation

I have a link hinged at one end and attached to a rectangular object via another hinge in the other end as shown. Now, I was wondering how would I maintain the orientation of the rectangular object regardless of the rotation of the link.

I know this sounds like a vague question but I am just out of ideas on achieving this effect.

[image]

Comment: Attach a motor?

Comment: This question (v1) seems to be engineering rather than physics.

Comment: @Qmechanic, you are right. Found my solution though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use two parallel arms:

[image: Rotate]

This constrains your block to remain parallel to the wall because the wall, block and arms form a parallelogram.

Comment: Elegant. I wonder why I didn't think of this before asking this question considering how simple the solution is.

Comment: @BLOB Ever used a drafter? This sort of construction is pretty common, really, but not always noticed.

Answer (score 2):

Attach a weight to the rectangle object so that it's centre of gravity is brought lower than its hinge point.

Comment: Clever and clear (+1) but I think the OP wants an orientation independent solution!

Comment: Nice but this arrangement would work only on vertical arrangement of the entire system.

Answer (score 2):

If you would attach the hinge right at the centre of mass, as the entire rod moves the centre of mass will be directly influenced and no torque would act due to absence of perpendicular dictance between action of gravity and your appled force for rotation. 
As no torque would be applied, the orientation would be maintained with just one rod.

Comment: What about the torque due to friction at the hinge?

Comment: I assumed a little bit of idealistic environment, my apologies. But still I am nkt able to imagine where would the torque of friction if it does play a part tend to rotate the block, isn't the perpendicular distance zero ?